# Send push notification to ios app : Google cloud

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-platform

I have hosted my PHP code on google cloud.

I want to send push notifications to ios app. I have enabled port 2195 and 2196.

While sending the push notification I got the following error :

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL: Connection reset by peer
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
> ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error)

I am not much familiar with Google Cloud. What should I do to make it working?

Here is code:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', PEM_FILE_PATH . 'apns-dev.pem');

$fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {
    $data['msgs'] = "Failed to connect $err $errstr \n";
} else {
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n", 32) . pack("H*", str_replace(" ", "", $deviceToken)) . pack("n", strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg);

    if (!$result) {
        $data['msgs'] = 'Message not delivered'; //. PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $data['msgs'] = 'Success'; //. PHP_EOL;
    }

    fclose($fp);
}
return $data;
```

Comment: What cloud? Compute Engine or App Engine?

Comment: It is Compute Engine

Comment: Are you opening a connection, sending a message, closing connection and then looping and doing it all over again?

Comment: @SantoshJagtap:Yes. I have also tried single notification, but same error.

Comment: Are you using certificates? This happened to me when I was using the bad certificate. Review your code and your certificates in order to see that all is right. Test it first with the sandbox APNS test server

Comment: @eloibm : Out put of the command > openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert apns-dev.pem -key apns-dev.pem
CONNECTED(00000003)

Comment: This is the output but the connection suddently is closed? This is because you are using dev certificates (or the names contains dev) to connect to the oficial server. If you want to test with dev server the url is this one `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`. Nevertheless, there should be a problem in your PHP code that creates the SSL connection. Can you edit your post and put your PHP code?

Comment: @eloibm : I have edited the question and added php code.

Comment: The `apns-dev.pem` that you are sending to the server has been created with the combination of the APNS certificate and the private key that you have generated?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem when we are trying to send data to the APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) servers is the **SSL certificates**.

APNS uses this technology in order to serve more secure connection to its users.

As it is said at [APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1): "*Each certificate is limited to a single app and is also limited to one of two development environments, each with its own assigned hostname*". So you can use two environments

- **Development** (testing environment): `ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`
- **Production** (once the app is launched): `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

If you want to test if you can connect to APNS server, just try the following command:

```
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.172.232.226...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you get an error then make sure your firewall allows outgoing connections on port 2195.

Then you can test if your SSL certificate and private key are working and it can be set up a secure connection:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert YourDevCert.pem -key YourPrivateKey.pem
Enter pass phrase for YourPrivateKey.pem: ******
```

If this works it means that your certificates are correctly set up (you should see a whole bunch of output, which is openssl letting you know what is going on under the hood).

Once knowing all of this information, I see that you have one mistake in your code and also you should check something else:

- Check if you have a good connection with APNS server.
- Check that your `$payload` variable is a json string.
- Check that you have a correct `$deviceToken`.
- Check that you are using the right certificate with the right environtment. In this case, you are setting a `apns-dev.pem` certificate and you are sending it to the **production** environment (I interpret that your production certificate is `apns-prod.pem` so check it).
- Check that your PHP file can find your certificate.
- One of **your problems**, you haven't set any password for your private key. You should add the following line once you have added your certificate:

`stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "passphrase", "your_private_key");`

If you have some troubles or doubts, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) to send my first APNS Push Notifications.